# What is 'data' in python's urrlib2.Request?

Tags: python, request

I am new to Web requests . I saw a piece of code that does HTML PDF conversion like this :

```
headers = {'content-type': 'text/html', 'accept': 'application/pdf'}
urllib2.Request(url, data=html, headers=headers) # html is a string and it works fine
```

The url does the pdf conversion and it needs html as input .

Why is 'data' keyword argument so important ? Why can't be clubbed as just another param ?

I would have thought that `urllib2.Request(url, params = {'data': html})` where data is just one of the key value pairs . And server does it processing accordingly .

Why do we need 'data' as something seperate from other parameters ?

Is it because we specify  'content-type' in the header and it bound to the data keyword as a convention ?

I am writing an API that makes everything is request like a keyword arguement , for a simple library purpose . So I would like to know when is data required and when is not as well . I do understand params but 'data' is that mandatory or only for post requests where you have a specific content-type to sent to server? What if I have multiple content types now ?

Comment: When the data attribute is provided, the request is sent as POST. It is not mandatory, it can be None, if it is none (or not provided) it is sent as GET. This is all described here:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request

Comment: Does request also have the same convention ? I ask so because in request we have request.get . So request.get(url, data=something) would be converted to a POST ? And how is this data seen at the server side any idea ?

Comment: I have continued in an answer, as the comments are hard to show code in.

Comment: Right your comments as like an answer , I was thinking of asking you to post an answer .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the data attribute is provided, the request is sent as POST. It is not mandatory, it can be None, if it is none (or not provided) it is sent as GET. This is all described here: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html#urllib2.Request

> Does request also have the same convention ? I ask so because in
>   request we have request.get . So request.get(url, data=something)
>   would be converted to a POST ? And how is this data seen at the server
>   side any idea ?

`request.get(url, data="test")` would be sent as a GET request with "test" as the body of the request. This is the raw HTTP request:

```
GET /headers HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: httpbin.org\r\nContent-Length: 4\r\nAccept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress\r\nAccept: */*\r\nUser-Agent: python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Windows/7\r\n\r\ntest
```

Formatted:

```
GET /headers HTTP/1.1
Host: httpbin.org
Content-Length: 4
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, compress
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.2.1 CPython/2.7.5 Windows/7

test
```

The server will in most cases just ignore it.